# Function argument allocation?

Tags: c, memory-management, arguments, malloc

```
char* foo(char* str)
{
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%s", foo(malloc(10)));

    return 1;
}
```

I am just wondering if that is a proper declaration. Will the output be a null string?

Is it actually allocated?

Is the scope extended and it is saved into a dynamic memory area?

Will it cause any u/b or just crash?

On my test compiller (Pelles C), it crashes.

Comment: I think the source of the crash is that the string doesn't reach its end into its first 10 characters.

Comment: Yes that is a serious leak. Since it is not NULL-terminated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`malloc(10)` allocates 10 bytes of contiguous memory.
Indeed, `malloc()` attempts to allocate this amount of memory, but in general one cannot be sure if this was succesfull.
A comparisson against NULL is need before going further with the execution flow of the program.

Let us suppose that the 10 bytes has been properly allocated.
It results in a `void*` pointer to an allocated object occupying 10 bytes.
When passed as argument to `foo()`, it is converted to a `char*` pointer.
Since `char` objects occupy exactly 1 byte, the 10 allocated bytes can be reinterpreted as an array of 10 characters.
The address pointed by the `char*` pointer `str` can be accessed safely as an array of 10 characters.

However, a `char*` pointer is not the same as a "C string".
A "C string" is an array of char ended by a null character.
So, the question here is if your parameter `str` has such a null character `'\0'` marking the end of the string.

It is very probably that this is not the case.
If there are a null character beyond the "legal" boundary of the 10 allocated bytes, the function `printf()` will be trying to access wrong memory places.

Crash is the most probable result.

Comment: A crash is a possible but unlikely result. Initially, freshly malloced memory will contain zeroes (this is always the case on POSIX systems). Even if it doesn't, printf is likely to encounter a NUL before reaching an unmapped location, resulting in printing gibberish but no crash.

Comment: @JimBalter: From the standard: 7.22.3.4(2) _The malloc function allocates space for an object whose size is speciﬁed by size and
whose value is indeterminate._ The OP's compiler is PellesC, wich run under Windows.

Comment: I know what the standard says (I was on the C Standards committee), and it has no bearing on what I wrote ... "indeterminate" simply means that the standard doesn't mandate the content. More relevant is the fact that in debug builds under Windows, malloc fills blocks with identifiable non-zero bytes. But even then, printf is likely to reach a NUL before reaching unmapped memory. Since what will happen depends on what version of what compiler is being used and several other factors, it's "indeterminate" as to what is "the most probable result" ... except that it will be undesired.

Answer (score 2):

While using `%s` format specifier ensure that the pointer is `'\0'` terminated. In your 
example memory is allocated but it is not `'\0'` terminated.